# OpenMP critical sections in called classes (different than parallel loop)

Tags: c++, openmp

My question concerns OpenMP critical sections in classes called by a parallellized for-loop which is not part of the same class as the critical section(s).
Can critical sections be used this way?

Here is an example:

```
class TestFunction
{
    TestFunction( SomeSharedObject& _obj) : obj_(_obj) {}
    public:
    void possibly_change_sharedobj( ) 
    {
        #pragma omp critical(myCriticalSection)
        {
            obj_.do_something();
        }
    }
    SomeSharedobject& obj_;
};

class ClassWithParallelloop
{
     void parallelloop()
     {
         #pragma omp parallel for
         for( int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
         {
             TestFunction testfn( myobj_);
             testfn.possibly_change_sharedobj();
         } 
     }
     SomeSharedObject myobj_; 
 };
```

Q: is the shared object (myobj_) protected against concurrent changes?

Comment: The OpenMP `critical` construct is in the dynamic scope of the combined `parallel for`, therefore it would work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `myobj_` is not "protected against concurrent changes", because that's not what *critical sections* do.

What they *do*, is prevent code in those sections from running simultaneously. So, ***as long as*** you guarantee that no code **outside the *critical section(s)**** access `myobj_`, you'll have prevented concurrent access (this is implicit protection).

Answering the other question: It is not a problem (not even relevant) that the `omp ciritical` pragma is not inside the `omp parallel` section, lexically.